# User handlebar expression to get user name in SharePoint PnP search

Tags: sharepoint, handlebars.js

I'm using PnP Search in SharePoint online. I'm creating a search result web part and trying to add column for user name. The returned string in this column is as below:

```
Kate.Smith@contoso.com | Smith, Kate | 693A30232E...7175
i:0#.f|membership|Kate.Smith@contoso.com
```

I need to grab the user name `'Smith, Kate'` only to display.
But I did not find any guide on this online.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to split by '|' for that we have inbuilt handle bars you can use in layout.

To Split by '|': `{{split item.userField "|"}}`

Split Handle bar documentation: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#split

And after splitting it you have to take middle one right, so give the index of it.

To get Index Value:

```
{{itemAt (split item.userField "|") 1}}`
{{itemAt (split "Kate.Smith@contoso.com | Smith, Kate | 693A30232E...7175" "|") 1}}
```

Documentation for ItemAt: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#itemAt

Answer (score 0):

try with this link [how-to-customize-the-handlebars-template-in-pnp-modern-search-web-part](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/how-to-customize-the-handlebars-template-in-pnp-modern-search-web-part/)

1. Manage persona fields
2. Manage persona fields configuration page
3. Leave only `{{FirstName}} {{LastName}}`

Look at this answers too https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280360/customizing-the-pnp-people-search-handlebar-template-in-sharepoint-online